# I tried to test a file download and pause/resume but keep getting System.Net.WebException: 'The underlying connection was closed. how to resolve?

Tags: c#, winforms

when i try to download the file directly from the website it's working fine. there is no problem with the site.

System.Net.WebException: 'The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.'

System.Net.WebException
HResult=0x80131509
Message=The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.
Source=System
StackTrace:
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at File_Download.FileDownloader.GetContentLength() in D:\Csharp Projects\File Download\FileDownloader.cs:line 56
at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()

the exception is on line 56:

```
var response = request.GetResponse()
```

the class code

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace File_Download
{
    public class FileDownloader
    {
        private volatile bool _allowedToRun;
        private readonly string _sourceUrl;
        private readonly string _destination;
        private readonly int _chunkSize;
        private readonly IProgress<double> _progress;
        private readonly Lazy<long> _contentLength;

        public long BytesWritten { get; private set; }
        public long ContentLength => _contentLength.Value;

        public bool Done => ContentLength == BytesWritten;

        public FileDownloader(string source, string destination, int chunkSizeInBytes = 10000 /*Default to 0.01 mb*/, IProgress<double> progress = null)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(source))
                throw new ArgumentNullException("source is empty");
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(destination))
                throw new ArgumentNullException("destination is empty");

            _allowedToRun = true;
            _sourceUrl = source;
            _destination = destination;
            _chunkSize = chunkSizeInBytes;
            _contentLength = new Lazy<long>(GetContentLength);
            _progress = progress;

            if (!File.Exists(destination))
                BytesWritten = 0;
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    BytesWritten = new FileInfo(destination).Length;
                }
                catch
                {
                    BytesWritten = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        private long GetContentLength()
        {
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_sourceUrl);
            request.Method = "HEAD";

            using (var response = request.GetResponse())
                return response.ContentLength;
        }

        private async Task Start(long range)
        {
            if (!_allowedToRun)
                throw new InvalidOperationException();

            if (Done)
                //file has been found in folder destination and is already fully downloaded 
                return;

            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_sourceUrl);
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)";
            request.AddRange(range);

            using (var response = await request.GetResponseAsync())
            {
                using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (var fs = new FileStream(_destination, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                    {
                        while (_allowedToRun)
                        {
                            var buffer = new byte[_chunkSize];
                            var bytesRead = await responseStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length).ConfigureAwait(false);

                            if (bytesRead == 0) break;

                            await fs.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                            BytesWritten += bytesRead;
                            _progress?.Report((double)BytesWritten / ContentLength);
                        }

                        await fs.FlushAsync();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public Task Start()
        {
            _allowedToRun = true;
            return Start(BytesWritten);
        }

        public void Pause()
        {
            _allowedToRun = false;
        }
    }
}
```

using it in form1

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace File_Download
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private FileDownloader fw;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ReportProgress(double progress)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = (int)(progress * 100);
            label1.Text = string.Format("ContentLength: {0} | BytesWritten: {1}", fw.ContentLength, fw.BytesWritten);
        }

        private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Start the download only when the "Start" button is clicked
            if (fw == null || fw.Done)
            {
                fw = new FileDownloader("https://hil-speed.hetzner.com/100MB.bin", @"D:\100MB.bin", 5120, new Progress<double>(ReportProgress));
            }

            // Start the download
            fw.Start().ContinueWith(t => label1.Text = "Done");
        }

        private void btnPause_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (btnPause.Text == "Pause")
            {
                fw.Pause();
                btnPause.Text = "Resume";
            }
            else
            {
                // Resume the download
                fw.Start().ContinueWith(t => label1.Text = "Done");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ".ContinueWith"? Why not await?

Comment: I believe the issue is with the source URL.  The connection is not completing and that is giving the error.  Since it is working when downloading the issue is NOT HTTPS which uses TLS for encryption.  So I suspect the issue with with Authentication.  Does site use Window Credentials or a two part Authentication like OAUTH2?

Comment: Does the target support/allow `HEAD`?